# How can I perform this query?

Tags: sql, django

One of the fields in my database is a string containing multiple usernames separated by commas (ex: 'wasingej, doej, hamm, ...").  I want to do a query where a database entry (or multiple) is selected if a supplied username appears in the string containing multiple usernames.

How would I do this?

Comment: If you have a choice in the matter, you should break string delimited values into separate columns.  Thats how data belongs in databases.

Comment: Why have you stored a comma delimited list in your model? That seems like the first part of your problem.

Comment: use the contains keyword

Comment: CONTAINS sounds promising, but how to match CONTAINS to 'Dan,...' at beginning of list without matching ',...JorDan,...' too?

Comment: contains wouldnot look into terms present in between text? like clause would also do.. '%name_here%'

Comment: I think this is basic to think beforehand about how insertion, retrieval and searching of data will work in current database design.

Comment: I feel like I should explain what I am trying to do more thoroughly.  The database I am designing contains information about email lists which are managed by the program Mailman.  Each list should have one or more administrator users (this is where I thought a comma delimited string of usernames would be handy).  If having a comma-delimited string is not the correct way of going about this, how can I create a field in django which is an arbitrarily sized list of elements, and then do a query on that list?

Comment: If you have a list of users in the database already, you might consider adding a column on the user table is_admin which is set to TRUE for only admins.  Not sure about the django side though.

Comment: You seem to have tagged this question `django`. If so, and if you're using Django's user authentication system, why not simply use a `ManyToManyField(User)`?

Comment: @DanFarrell: Django already has an `is_staff` column in the `User` table in the included `contrib.auth` app. This flag marks which users can use the included `contrib.admin` app, but could be used for other purposes, too. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     usernames varchar(255), 
    );

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(usernames)
VALUES
('Dan'),
('DAN,SCOTT'),
('Jordan,Michael,Dan'),
('Adam,Kelly,Daniel,Roger,Sue'),
('Crystal,Kari,Logan,Daniella'),
('Jon,Dan,Xerxes,Brian'),
('Samantha,Keylin,Dan')
;
SELECT * from supportContacts WHERE 
  usernames = 'Dan' or -- only dan
   usernames LIKE 'Dan,%' or  -- begins
  usernames LIKE ',Dan,' or -- within
  usernames LIKE '%,Dan' -- ends
```

It has the problem that it doesn't match on case - not an issue if your input isn't case sensitive anyway - but it is Better than Raging Bull's answer because it doesn't match the names within other names ( my fiddle shows this by not matching 'Daniella' or 'Daniel' )

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72493/4

Comment: A lot easier to understand, too.

Answer (score 0):

**USING** `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @CONDITION VARCHAR(255)
SET @CONDITION = '%'' UNION SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName LIKE ''%'

DECLARE @Unames VARCHAR(255)       --List of username you pass from your program
SET @Unames = 'wasingej,doej,hamm' --Taking it as an example

DECLARE @FullQuery VARCHAR(255)
SET @FullQuery = 'SELECT *
  FROM TableName
 WHERE ColName LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@Unames,',',@CONDITION)+'%'''  --Replacing comma with @Condition

EXEC(@FullQuery)
```

At last, you can get your query in the variable `@FullQuery` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName LIKE '%wasingej%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName LIKE '%doej%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName LIKE '%hamm%'
```

See example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/050ed/34).

Comment: I was playing with this too, but the problem is twofold - firstly, the LIKE isn't case sensitive ( can't figure out a way to solve _that_ ).  Secondly, You're not ensuring that you don't match a partial name - example, you're looking for 'hamm' but your string would also match 'markhamm' or 'hammmond' or 'whatahammyname'

Comment: Why the spaces?  Is there something I'm missing?